# Adding text immediately after the main text of a scrlttr2 letter

Tags: scrlttr2

A letter normally ends with a signature. I've want to add text after this point. To be clear, I don't want it right at the bottom of the letter, I want the text to be more or less immediately following the main text of the letter, preferably with a user-adjustable gap. Is this possible, or will the structure of `scrlttr2` not allow it?

Comment: Member with +3k and no MWE?  -1.

Comment: Insert the additional text after `\closing` but inside the `letter` environment. Maybe you can use `\ps`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert additional text after `\closing`.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\setkomavar{signature}{Signature}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{xxx}
\opening{Hi,}
\blindtext
\closing{Best regards}
\blindtext
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

You can also use `\ps` before the additional text. Then the first paragraph is not indented and  if no `\parskip` is used, a vertical space of `\baselineskip` is added.

```
\documentclass[
  %parskip
]{scrlttr2}
\setkomavar{signature}{Signature}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{xxx}
\opening{Hi,}
\blindtext
\closing{Best regards}
\ps
\blindtext
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

You could patch `\ps` to change the vertical space between `signature` and the additional text:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\ps{\vspace{-1\baselineskip}}{}{\PatchFailed}
```